# How can I generate a pdf in Reportlab from information from different documents?

Tags: python, reportlab

Would anybody who knows, help me understand how this code can work to produce the required page.

```
c = canvas.Canvas("sample.pdf")
sample1 = csv.reader(open('sample1.csv'))
for i in sample1:
    first = i[0]
    c.drawString(100,800,first)
    sample2 = csv.reader(open('sample2.csv'))
    for x in sample2:
        sec = x[0]
        third = x[1]
        fourth = x[2]
        c.drawString(200,700,sec)
        c.drawString(200,600,third)
        c.drawString(200,500,fourth)
    c.showPage()
c.save()
```

As it is, it prints only the documents in sample2 successfully and one page of the items in sample1....
I'm trying to extract information from two documents to use in generating one pdf.

Comment: why do you nested `for`-loops?

Comment: I thought that's the way it can get to work but it doesn't. I don't have an option.

Comment: how many pages you expected ?

Comment: @furas. Five pages because there are 5 rows in each of the two documents

Comment: so you need version with `zip()` - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but I would do this without nesting loops

I assum you have three rows in sample1 `X`, `Y`, `Z` and three rows in sample2 `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`

It creates three pages `X`, `Y`, `Z` and next three pages `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import csv

c = canvas.Canvas("sample.pdf")

#sample1 = csv.reader(open('sample1.csv'))
#sample2 = csv.reader(open('sample2.csv'))
sample1 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
sample2 = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]

for a in sample1:
    c.drawString(100, 800, a[0])  # X / Y / Z
    c.showPage()

for b in sample2:
    c.drawString(200, 700, b[0])  # A / D / G
    c.drawString(200, 600, b[1])  # B / E / H
    c.drawString(200, 500, b[2])  # C / F / I
    c.showPage()

c.save()
```

But if you want to create only three pages `X+ABC`, `Y+DEF`, `Z+GHI` then you need `zip()`

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import csv

c = canvas.Canvas("sample.pdf")

#sample1 = csv.reader(open('sample1.csv'))
#sample2 = csv.reader(open('sample2.csv'))
sample1 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
sample2 = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]

for a, b in zip(sample1, sample2):
    c.drawString(100, 800, a[0])

    c.drawString(200, 700, b[0])
    c.drawString(200, 600, b[1])
    c.drawString(200, 500, b[2])

    c.showPage()

c.save()
```

---

**BTW:** If you need nine pages

- `X+ABC`, `X+DEF`, `X+GHI`
- `Y+ABC`, `Y+DEF`, `Y+GHI`
- `Z+ABC`, `Z+DEF`, `Z+GHI`

then you have to move `drawString( a[0])` and `showPage()` inside second loop

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import csv

c = canvas.Canvas("sample.pdf")

#sample1 = csv.reader(open('sample1.csv'))
sample1 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

for a in sample1:

    #sample2 = csv.reader(open('sample2.csv'))
    sample2 = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]

    for b in sample2:
        c.drawString(100, 800, a[0])

        c.drawString(200, 700, b[0])
        c.drawString(200, 600, b[1])
        c.drawString(200, 500, b[2])

        c.showPage()

c.save()
```